# Change display name for GitHub Actions Bot commit

Tags: git, github, github-actions

how can I change the display name for the GitHub Actions bot on a commit?

Currently I am using this workflow git parameters:

```yaml
- name: Configure Git
  run: |
    git config --local user.email "github-actions[bot]@users.noreply.github.com"
    git config --local user.name "GitHub Actions [Bot]"
          
- name: Commit files
  run: |
    git add ${{github.workspace}}/lib/bin/*
    git diff-index --quiet HEAD || git commit --author="GitHub Actions [Bot] <github-actions[bot]@users.noreply.github.com>" -m "Commited compiled binaries"
```

The result looks something like this:

[image]

`github-actions[bot] Commited compiled binaries`

But I want a result like this, like I specified in the config...:

`GitHub Actions [Bot] Commited compiled binaries`

Is this even possible to change the display name?

Comment: I'm not specifically aware of this being not possible, but I'd be surprised if it were so.

It would appear to me that the name it renders there is neither from the email or name fields of a commit, but from what it recognises internally as the username associated with that email. For instance a commit with your `my_gh_user_numeric_id+my_gh_account_name@users.noreply.github.com`, or with your account's login email, will show as a commit from your username.

Bots are the same e.g. a commit from `actions@github.com` will show up as beign from [this username](https://github.com/actions-user).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible and technically you're doing it right (the `--author`  option for `git-commit(1)` looks superfluous), but `github-actions[bot]@users.noreply.github.com` is a known email to Github, henceforth the email-to-user translation on Microsoft Github is in effect and the username / avatar is used.

Use a different emailaddress and you can choose the name to display and as long as the email is unknown to Microsoft Github, that name will be used instead of the username and the avatar is blanked.

The git history is not affected by this, it is only the display of the commits on `github.com` via HTTP in the hypertext interface.